# ClearCase list of files with given label type applied

Tags: report, clearcase, cleartool

We currently use clearcase on a project, and there is an HTML file that was generated with clearcase that contains all of the filenames of the files that were included in a label.

I am supposed to generate this file with a different label. I know how to get all of the filenames that were included in a label using the cleartool command line, but that doesn't help me with generating the file. I don't want to manually take that list and create the HTML file. So, how do I create this file?

I currently do not have a copy of the HTML file, but I have seen it. Hopefully this question isn't too confusing and too vague. I'm still relatively new to clearcase and just found out some of the cleartool commands today, so hopefully this is an easy question to answer.

Comment: Any news about that HTML file name and content? That would allow me to check if I have already seen that kind of file before.

Comment: It looks like it was produced by a report. I need to get the source mapped correctly using clearcase to see if I can run this report.

Comment: Ok. I remain available for any further details on that file, and will add specifics details to my answer then.

Comment: Would this ( http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?ratlid=cctocbody&rs=984&uid=swg21259167 ) helps with your report builder visibility issue?

Comment: I had to remove every other reference to perl other than clearcases to get it to work. Hopefully other things don't break.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure about the exact HTML file you are referring to. Do you have an example of its name, and of its content? If you edit your question with those data, I will be able to add to this answer.

But anyway, if that file is not generated *directly* by ClearCase, the solution remains to parse a [**`cleartool find`** command](http://www.samecs.com/commands/cleartool%20commands/find/find.htm#_Toc193967928) (see also [Additional examples of the cleartool find command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rcss=faqtt_1Q09&uid=swg21124425) article)

```
cleartool find . –version "lbtype(MY_LABEL-1.0)"
```

and to build your html file with, for instance, a Perl script.
You could even add this action into a ClearCase sub-menu entry, like illustrated in the [ten best scripts article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4687.html).

Comment: The cleartool works perfectly, unfortunately I can't get the report builder to show any options for reporting. It has something to do with my perl configuration, but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

What you might be looking for is Report Builder (also known in ClearCase Explorer as Report Wizard).  In Report Builder you can navigate to Elements/Labels which has the "Elements with Labels" and "Versions with Labels" reports.  After the report runs you have the option to save the results as HTML, XML, or CSV.