# Counting number of checkins per user in clearcase

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I would like to get the number of total checkins per user within a certain time frame. This is the kind of result I am looking for:

User: xxxxx Count: 432
User: yyyyy Count: 22

etc

I can use find to list all checkins done by a user, but I am only interested in the count!

Edit: Finding number of checkins per one (known) user at a time would also be ok!
Edit: I also need to filter on a certain filetype, e.g. *.java !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to experiment with [`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm), using directives from the [query language](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/query_language.htm) such has:

**`created_since`**: For instance, this limit a query for the month of May:

```
cleartool find . –version "{brtype(main_dev) && created_since(30-Apr) && (! created_since(31-May)) }" -print
```

**`-user (login-name)`** : this limit for a period, for a given user

```
cleartool find . -user user1 -element "{created_since(date1) && !created_since(date2)}" -print
```

So basically, you need to process the result of a find query, in order to sort it by user, and by filename extension.

---

The only *native* tool (so without counting external non-free third-party tool) would be to experiment with the [ClearCase Report Builder](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_rpt_ch.htm) (or "Report Wizard"), and see if you can set the right filters.
(mentioned in "[ClearCase list of files with given label type applied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2464597/6309)").

Comment: is this what the question was ? the user is asking for the count and already knows the FIND command, so do we need to improve this answer ?

Comment: @PulakAgrawal sure, it can be improved. I was pointing out some less known feature of the find command in order to filter the results and help achieving a count, but this is only a lead.