# clearcase command to find branch on which label is applied

Tags: label, branch, clearcase

I have label, and want to look it up in different clearcase vobs.

`cleartool diff -g -pre filename@@\main\branch\label`

So i need the filename(s) it touches and on which branch my label resides.

[ClearCase list of files with given label type applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289854/clearcase-list-of-files-with-given-label-type-applied)
solution gives list of files using that label. However it is very slow.

`cleartool find -all -version "lbtype(labelname)" -print`

I saw someone use another command which was way faster, to identify files. But it does not give branch.

`cleartool describe -fmt %c -type lbtype:labelname@/vobs/admin`

Can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the describe alone (of the `lbtype`) would not give you any file/version.
So the `cleartool find` remains a viable option.

> However it is very slow.

Maybe a find `-cview`, in the current view, might be faster: you would need to repeat that query for each vob, instead of relying on the `-all` option

```
cd /views/myViews/vobs/vob1
cleartool find . -cview -version "lbtype(LABEL)" -print

cd /views/myViews/vobs/vob2
cleartool find . -cview -version "lbtype(LABEL)" -print
```

Comment: As mentioned, I'm trying to find code changes made with this label, to review code. ie need differences between this vs previous version, in a large code base spanning many vobs. So using the label in config doesn't help. When I call it after describe, I do restrict find to a vob. Why/what is performance difference if find is called with cview? Since it's not necessary a label created by me/my-team, label is rarely in my local view.

Comment: @AtifHussain " label is rarely in my local view": label would be in your local view with the right config spec, as in Brian's answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't just use the label in a view configspec?

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * MYLABEL
element * /main/LATEST
```

Assuming you labeled the directories too, you would preselect everything you're looking for.